# std::string shrink_to_fit corrupts string

Tags: c++, string, stl, buffer

So I have this `std::string` object that gets filled by a C-Style function, like `strcpy`. The function can return anywhere between 10-100 characters, so I reserve 100 in the string.

But using `&buf[0]` works, but then when I try `shrink_to_fit()`, the string gets corrupted. How can I avoid this?

```
std::string buf;
buf.reserve(100);
//example of the function that can write to a buffer with 10-100 characters.
strcpy(&buf[0], "Hello");
buf.shrink_to_fit();
std::cout << buf << std::endl;
```

Comment: `reserve` does not change `size`. You are simply doing it wrong. You probably want `resize`. Also, why are you mixing C style string handling and C++ `string` objects?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`reserve()` sets the string's **capacity**, not its **size**.  Two different things.  The *capacity* is how much memory has been allocated to hold characters.  The *size* is how many characters inside of that allocated memory are actually valid.

`shrink_to_fit()` shrinks the *capacity* to match the current *size*.  But your string's *size* is always 0, so the string is effectively empty, not corrupted, whether you call `shrink_to_fit()` or not.  Printing a `std::string` prints characters up to its *size*, not to its *capacity*.

You need to use `resize()` instead of `reserve()`, eg:

```cpp
std::string buf;
buf.resize(100);
//example of the function that can write to a buffer with 10-100 characters.
strcpy(&buf[0], "Hello");
buf.resize(strlen(buf.c_str()));
buf.shrink_to_fit();
std::cout << buf << std::endl;
```

That being said, `shrink_to_fit()` is not *required* to do anything, it is implementation-defined.  You might consider using a separate buffer to read characters into, and then construct your `std::string` from that buffer, eg:

```cpp
std::array<char, 100> buf;
//example of the function that can write to a buffer with 10-100 characters.
strcpy(buf.data(), "Hello");
std::string str(buf.data(), strlen(buf.data()));
std::cout << str << std::endl;
```

Or, in C++17 and later, you can use `std::string_view` instead, eg:

```cpp
std::array<char, 100> buf;
//example of the function that can write to a buffer with 10-100 characters.
strcpy(buf.data(), "Hello");
std::string_view sv(buf.data(), strlen(buf.data()));
std::cout << sv << std::endl;
```

Comment: `std::string str(buf.data(), strlen(buf.data()));` that's a little verbose, `std::string` constructor does that by default when only pointer is passed

Comment: @Slava True, however this was just an example. We don't know what C-style function the OP is actually calling to get the character data, or whether that data is null-terminated or not.  Maybe the function returns the number of characters written to the OP's buffer, we don't know.  So I wrote my examples to show how to construct a `std::string(_view)` given a pointer and count, just in case.

Comment: OK thank you. I needed to use the `GetTempPathW` winapi function. But these seem like good answers.

Comment: @ArushAgarampur In that case, `GetTempPathW()` DOES output a null-terminated string, but it ALSO returns the number of characters outputted NOT including the null terminator.  Also, to store the output of `GetTempPathW()` into a C++ string, you need to use `std::wstring(_view)` instead of `std::string(_view)`, unless you are planning on converting the outputted `wchar_t` data to ANSI or UTF-8.